# Why isn't my GUI loaded on the constructor?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I have a main class that on some point calls another class, with a constructor as below.

The constructor creates the GUI and I think should show it, but it doesnt. Why could this be?

```
public ModPackManager(){
    System.out.println("New modpackmanager");
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBounds(100, 100, 350, 87);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);
    {
        JLabel lblDownloadingModPack = new JLabel("Downloading and installing modpack, please wait...");
        lblDownloadingModPack.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblDownloadingModPack.setBounds(10, 11, 330, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblDownloadingModPack);
    }

    progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setBounds(10, 48, 330, 24);
    contentPanel.add(progressBar);

    label = new JLabel("0%");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setBounds(10, 29, 330, 14);
    contentPanel.add(label);
    try {
        installMods(getSelectedModPack());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), as well as ASCII art of how the GUI should appear at minimum size, as well as when assigned extra width/height.

Answer (score 1):

> Why could this be?

Trying to `setBounds(..)` as opposed to using layouts (with padding and borders).

Answer (score 0):

You never show anything, you just set it up.

While it's not entirely clear what exactly you're doing, or what classes you're using, if it's a `JFrame`:

```
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

You may want to comment out the `setUndecorated(true)` during development–it may make things impossible to see/find. To avoid a window manager sizing things away, perhaps a minimum:

```
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
```

I'm not sure what the spurious block around the label is for.

Comment: Ok, now the window appears, but it is just a white box, what could be the problem?

Comment: @zyngawow I don't know; it works fine for me--are you setting a minimum size?

Answer (score 0):

assuming ModPackManager is a JFrame, you should be able to make it visible by using:

```
setVisible(true);
```

Just call it after your other code in the constructor. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: It is a JFrame, and as i said to the other guy, just a small black box appears.